# Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. and can not install MySQL Server 5.7

Tags: 16.04, mysql

This is what I have done.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

This is the error I get.

```
chris@LivingRoomDell:~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not sure how to proceed from here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Chris

Comment: If you run 'dpkg -L | grep -i sql' do you have any other mysql packages installed? For example, do you have mariadb installed? I have had conflicts between mariadb and mysql.

Comment: It says you have held packages.  What is the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` If it returns results, then fix those issues (remove the listed packages and try to reinstall them if you really need them). If the dpkg command returns nothing, try using `sudo apt-get autoremove` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` returns nothing

Comment: while `dpkg -L | grep -i sql` just returned an error.  `chris@LivingRoomDell:/etc/apache2$ dpkg -L | grep -i sql
dpkg-query: error: --listfiles needs at least one package name argument`

Comment: I did get this information running this `chris@LivingRoomDell:/etc/apache2$ dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  mysql-common                                5.7.17-1ubuntu16.10                           amd64        MySQL Common
ii  php-mysql                                   1:7.0+35ubuntu6                               all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.0-mysql                                7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3                        amd64        MySQL module for PHP
`

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-server-5.7`?